# Delegate with several entity framework return types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, delegates

I am wondering if it is possible to create a delegate with several return types. Normally I would simply set the return type to "object" but since I am using entity framework and am new to this it doesn't appear to be quite so easy...

This is what I have:

```
private delegate List<Customer> SearchDelegate(string searchPhrase);
```

This is what I would like it to be:

```
private delegate List<Some sort of generic entity similar to object> SearchDelegate(string searchPhrase);
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Func can be used in some way I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods (including delegates) can't be overloaded just by return type.  You can either have several delegates:

```
private delegate List<Customer> SearchCustomerDelegate(string searchPhrase);
private delegate List<Order> SearchOrderDelegate(string searchPhrase);
```

or make the delegate generic:

```
private delegate List<T> SearchDelegate<T>(string searchPhrase);
```

Comment: The generic solution was exactly what I was looking for and what I tried to do. Thank you!

Comment: I need to have a SearchDelegate variable that's generic and known in the whole class, how would I go about creating it but not giving it a value? Something like:

private SearchDelegate<T> searchDelegate;

???

Comment: @Ohlafl Only classes and methods can be declared generically, so you need to either make the class generic or make the delegate non-generic.